# how can you copy files from azure storage to a vm

Tags: azure, automation, dsc

Ive been looking for a way to copy files from an azure storage to a vm using azure DSC but havent found any solutions

every time i run the dsc i get an error message as follows
"PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xRemoteFile failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: Invoking web request failed with error. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
Using automation account I have added the azure automation ok , not sure what is forbidden?? I have generated a SAS token and copied the URI as below so not sure what else i need to do???

the dsc is as below

```
configuration dscfiletest
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node localhost
    {
        File SetupDir {
            Type            = 'Directory'
            DestinationPath = 'C:\dsctest'
            Ensure          = "Present"    
        }
        
        xRemoteFile Package {  
            Uri             = "https://dscfiles.blob.core.windows.net/dsctesting/dsctesting.zip?sastokenhere" 
            DestinationPath = "C:\dsctest"
            #DependsOn      = "[File]SetupDir"
            MatchSource     = $false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell to test the URI? I had this, turns out I was generating a SAS Token from the wrong storage account!